# MAXScript: write numbers to file in full precision?

Tags: floating-point, precision, maxscript

I'm looking for a way to make 3ds Max to write values to a file in their full precision?
I realize Max uses 32 bit floats in its internal representations but the values it outputs to files usually seem to be of slightly lower precision.

The only function that seem to be able to write values to a file is `format "%" value to: f` this function outputs values that look like `0.48729`
I'm using [this converter](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html) to check the float representation of this number and see that in hex it is `0x3ef97e13`
if I try to play with its least significant digits I can get
`0.487291 = 0x3ef97e35`
`0.487292 = 0x3ef97e56`
`0.487293 = 0x3ef97e78`
so clearly, even the 32 bit number Max holds has more accuracy than what it outputs using this function.

The only reference I found for a better precision is to use `formattedprint` but that function doesn't seem to be able to write to a file.

Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feed the output of `formattedPrint` to `format` or `print` (depending on your use-case).

Comment: Ah, I didn't realize formattedPrint just returns a string, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Another option, if you want to guarantee perfect precision without long strings, is to store the binary representation of the number, as per the online converted you've referenced.  This is possible using MaxScript `bit.floatAsInt` and `bit.intAsFloat`.

Whenever you write a float value, reinterpret bits from float->int.  Whenever you read the same value, reinterpret bits from int->float.  Here's an example:

```
d = 1.0 / 3.0
w = bit.floatAsInt d -- when writing to disk
r = bit.intAsFloat w -- when reading from disk
d==r -- verify as identical
```

Otherwise, you'll need about 30 decimal places via `formattedPrint d format:".30f"`